# How to change these high order ODEs into a system of 1st order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Trying to know how to reshape the following two high-order ODEs into a system of first order ODEs, but can't get it right. Tried to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cq3bPBePE8E&t=576s but didn't helped somehow.

a) Here is the first high-order ODE:
$u''(x)+u(x)+u(x)^3=0$   with initial values: $u(0)=0$ and $u′(0)= 0$

b) Here is the second high-order ODE: 
$u_1'(x) = 98u_1(x) + 198u_2'(x)$ and $u_2'(x) = −99u_1(x) − 199u_2(x)$ with initial values: $u_1(0)=1$ and $u_2(0)=0$

What would be each one, if we reshape it to a system of first-order ODEs?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The second system already seems to be a system of first order ODEs, since no term has derivative higher than 1.

The first system can be converted as follows:

Let $v(x) \equiv u'(x)$. Hence, $v'(x) = u''(x)$. Replacing $u''(x)$ with $v'(x)$ gives the equations:

\begin{align*}
&u'(x) = v(x) \\
&v'(x) = u(x) + u(x)^3 \quad \text{(Since $v'(x) = u''(x)$)}
\end{align*}

Since $u'(x) = 0$ in the initial conditions, this means that $v(x) = u'(x) = 0$ in the initial conditions.